# How to implement scroll view inside scroll view

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I implement a scroll view inside a scroll view like the GIF below? Please help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/elEOI.gif

Comment: I think this effect is created by using position:sticky to nav node

Comment: Thanks you.
I was able to solve it by using the sticky_headers package.